# Wix ICE32: Possible Mis-Aligned Foreign Keys

Tags: wix, wix3.11

When adding a merge module (Visual FoxPro Oledb V9) to a wix project, I get the following error message:

```
error LGHT0204: ICE32: Possible Mis-Aligned Foreign Keys
```

Using WiX Toolset v3.11

I get no indication of the table in which the keys are misaligned from the output.

I have tried opening the vfpoledb.msm in Orca, but I can't seem to find anything that looks like it is mismatched in terms of field sizes.

The merge module is being included with:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Merge Id="VFPOleDb" SourceFile="$(var.resources)\vfp-ole-db-merge-module\vfpoledb.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>

      ...
</DirectoryRef>

<Feature Id="MainApplication" 
         Title="Application Title"
         Level="1" 
         ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR" 
         Absent="disallow">

  <MergeRef Id="VFPOleDb" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="MainComponents" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ShortcutComponents" />

</Feature>
```

This merge module was previously included in an InstallShield installer project with no apparent issues. I've since converted across to using Wix but can't seem to get the installer to build with this merge module included (other merge modules are included e.g. vc++ runtime).

I can confirm that removing the merge module from the xml with no other modifications then allows the installer to build (removing the Merge and MergeRef elements for the merge module).

I've searched the internet to try and find suggestions to resolve this, with the only page I can find suggesting adjusting the table schema using Orca, but as mentioned, I get no further info on what table is causing the problem.

Any advice appreciated on how to either resolve the issue, elicit more information as to the offending table within the .msm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build from the command line and you'll get the misalignment(s). Visual Studio won't show multiple lines for a single error.

Comment: perfect, this showed me the tables and fields causing the problem, I was then able to easily use Orca to update the field size (from 32 to 38). This then solved the issue.

Comment: See my answer about using the EnsureTable element to make this go away.

Answer (score 0):

Run validation on the built MSI to see which tables are effected then use the EnsureTable element to tell WiX to put this empty table in.  This will happen prior to merging of the merge modules and will make the error go away.